# Two different LINQ queries against the same Entity Framework DbSet, both return the same results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Assuming I have:

```
class ContractContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<ACTIVITY> ACTIVITYs { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following code, where startSnapshot and endSnapshot are integers with values 1 and 2:

```
var activitiesStart = contractContext.ACTIVITYs.Where(a => a.VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID == startSnapshot);
var activitiesEnd = contractContext.ACTIVITYs.Where(a => a.VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID == endSnapshot);
```

Those two queries will return the same result. That result will be the result from the first one of those two queries that executes. So if I force them both to execute with a ToList(),

```
var activitiesStart = contractContext.ACTIVITYs.Where(a => a.VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID == startSnapshot).ToList();
var activitiesEnd = contractContext.ACTIVITYs.Where(a => a.VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID == endSnapshot).ToList();
```

Then the result stored in activitiesEnd will be the result from the activitiesStart query. If I execute the activitiesEnd query first then the opposite will be true. What's going on? I understand that they are the same context, and I guess I can see how it *might* combine the queries if I create them both before either is executed. In the second case, however, one is executed before the other is even created so why is it trampling the second query?

Generated SQL (same for both):

```
{SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ACTIVITY_ID] AS [ACTIVITY_ID], 
    [Extent1].[ACTIVITY_NAME] AS [ACTIVITY_NAME], 
    [Extent1].[WBS_ID] AS [WBS_ID], 
    [Extent1].[VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID] AS [VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID], 
    [Extent1].[DUE_DATE] AS [DUE_DATE], 
    [Extent1].[IS_COMPLETE] AS [IS_COMPLETE]
FROM [p6].[ACTIVITY] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID] = @p__linq__0}
```

## Example

```
var activitiesStart = contractContext.ACTIVITYs.Where(a => a.VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID == 1).ToList();
var activitiesEnd = contractContext.ACTIVITYs.Where(a => a.VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID == 2).ToList();

foreach (var item in activitiesStart)
{
    Debug.Write(item.VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID + " ");
}

Debug.WriteLine("");

foreach (var item in activitiesEnd)
{
    Debug.Write(item.VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID + " ");
}

Debug.WriteLine("");
```

This prints out two rows of ones, because activitiesStart was executed first. If I swap them I get two rows of twos. The SQL Server Profiler shows that the queries were properly sent to the server.

Comment: What are the values of startSnapshot and endSnapshot? How are those getting assigned?

Comment: I don't see any reason why they would affect each other.  When you debug up to the first statement, what are the values of startSnapshot and endSnapShot?

Comment: They are parameters to the function, and in my test case are 1 (start) and 2 (end). I'll update the question.

Comment: I don't think the actual values of `startSnapshot` and `endSnapshot` are relevant, so long as we all understand the implication that the values are different

Comment: Take a look at the generated SQL as well.

Comment: @SteveGreene, added. The only thing that makes sense, unless there is something I'm missing, is that `@p__linq__0` is getting set on the first query executed and isn't overridden for the second query.

Comment: I think maybe you are seeing something wrong in your debugger, I seriously doubt that the results are what you are describing as if that were the case EF would be almost unusable. The query generated makes sense but each execution of that query would have a different value for parameter `@p__linq__0` (1 and 2 based on your input above). Also `Those two queries will return the same result` is not accurate, they both return `IQueryable<ACTIVITY>` types but they are definitely not the same as each would generate a query with a different parameter.

Comment: Why do you think they're the same? Seeing something in debugger, printing something, what are you looking at that makes you say they're the "same"?

Comment: So one more request: you can capture the executed query as well in Sql Server Profiler (I am assuming sql server). This should have the parameter value listed, you should see that they have different values. Also check your code, if you are using a `const` in a different library for `startSnapshot` and `endSnapshot` and ever had a wrong value then you would have to recompile the whole project as const are literal values substituted at compile time. This would also give an illusion that it is not working as both values could still be the same.

Comment: The fact that the generated SQL is the same (it should be) doesn't mean the value of the `@p__linq__0` parameter is the same, nor the result.

Comment: Via the SQL Server Profiler I can see that the parameters are correctly sent to SQL. However when I loop through both collections and print the VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID of each activity object, both loops print out the value from the collection whose LINQ query was executed first.

Comment: I've updated the original post to show what I just described. My debugger (Visual Studio 2015) and the output of the for loops matches.

Comment: Take sql captured in profiler and run in ssms, varying the order. Just to super double check that sql is pulling back the values you expect? Long shot, I know...

Comment: Is `ACTIVITY` a regular table, or a view?

Comment: It's a regular table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure this out. My solution was to use AsNoTracking on the first one executed.

```
var activitiesStart = contractContext.ACTIVITYs.AsNoTracking.Where(a => a.VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID == startSnapshot).ToList();
var activitiesEnd = contractContext.ACTIVITYs.Where(a => a.VARIANCE_SNAPSHOT_ID == endSnapshot).ToList();
```

Comment: Still, this shows that something isn't right in your model. I've never seen anything like this happening. I wouldn't settle for a work-around. If you don't get to the bottom of it, sooner or later it'll cause you more trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get some crosstalk between queries due to the way deferred execution works. The queries will run against the parameter's value at the time of execution (ie when it is ToList() or consumed otherwise).

```
            var idA = 614;
            var idB = 130;

            var context = DbModel.ContextManager.Prism.dbo(DBName_Static);
            var custA = context.Customer.Where(x => x.Id == idA);
            var custB = context.Customer.Where(x => x.Id == idB);

            //different results (correct)
            var custA_forcedBefore = custA.ToList();
            var custB_forcedBefore = custB.ToList();

            //change the value of the input params to be the same
            idA = idB;

            //same results (incorrect). Because execution was deferred til after the parameter values were changed
            var custA_forcedAfter = custA.ToList();
            var custB_forcedAfter = custB.ToList();
```

Edit: I should note that when I ran into this issue it was not all in the same function. The value of the input parameters had been changed way up the stack after I had falsely assumed the queries had already executed.

Comment: This makes complete sense to me - I would guess that EF binds a reference to the parameter and not the value of the parameter. However if you look at the third code block in my post you'll see that I'm executing the queries with different variables. There is never a time when I'm setting one to be equal to the other. Also, see the Example section where I've hardcoded the values and I get the same issue.

Comment: @TomSchultz Given that you've done the immediate ToList() and confirmed the parameter values in sql profiler, I would tend to agree that it is not the deferred execution parameter value issue. It is mighty weird tho...